# Sharing JWT between Cross-Port Applications using postMessage

Tags: javascript, authentication, jwt, single-sign-on, cross-origin-read-blocking

I have two applications running on my localhost, each on a different port (localhost:3000 and localhost:3002). My goal is to redirect a user from localhost:3000 to localhost:3002 while passing a JWT (JSON Web Token) between the two applications. However, my current implementation using the `postMessage` method isn't working as expected.

Here's what I've tried:

Sender (localhost:3000):

```js
        const targetWindow = window.open("http://localhost:3002", "_blank");

            if (targetWindow) {
                targetWindow.addEventListener("load", () => {
                    const jwtToken = "my_jwt_token";
                    targetWindow.postMessage({ jwtToken }, "http://localhost:3002");
                });
            }
```

Receiver (localhost:3002):

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
      if (event.origin === "http://localhost:3000") {
          const { jwtToken } = event.data;
        }
    });
  }, [])
```

However, I'm not seeing any messages in the console when I print the "message" event. Could you please help me identify what might be causing this issue? Is there a better approach to achieving my goal of sharing a JWT between these two applications running on different ports?

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shared the jwt token throw cockles using `universal-cookie`

Sender (localhost:3000):

```js
const jwtToken = 'your_jwt_token_here';
const cookies = new Cookies();
cookies.set('jwtToken', jwtToken, { path: '/' });
```

Receiver (localhost:3002):

```js
const cookies = new Cookies();
const jwtToken = cookies.get('jwtToken')
```

Note:
Dont forget to clean the cookies after extracting the jwtToken

Answer (score 0):

JWT tokens are safe to publish openly, so the pretty standard way to do it is to provide a query parameter: `localhost:3002?JWT=my-jwt-token`, which later is extracted from there and validated by whatever backends the `localhost:3002`.

This is the simplest solution I can imagine without hidden unwanted side effects.

Comment: No, they're not safe to publish openly. They're safe in the sense that they cannot be tampered with, but whoever gets a hold of the token can use that token to do things on behalf of who the token was issued to.

Comment: @Fred nah, there is no notion of "who the token was issued". Token may or may not use cryptography - both symmetric (HS) or assymentric (RS) ways of doing it. In either case "issued" is not a required part of a JW token; in fact, it can be arbitrary JSON. So it is allowed to not be issued to a particular someone at all.